# How to fix "The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Repository repo, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger" in Xunit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit

I'm writing some tests for a test-driven-development app using Xunit. But for some reason, at the moment I initialize the constructor, the server throws an exception

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Repository repo, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger

This is the repository:

```
public class Repository 
{
    private IList<Subject> _subjects = new List<Subject>()
    {
        new Subject() 
            { 
                SubjectId = Guid.Parse("de331c36-6b31-4dd9-b50d-f677e51b987c"), 
                Title = "Math", 
                Credits = 8
            };       
    };

    public IEnumerable<Subject> GetAll() => _subjects;

    public Subject? GetById(Guid id) =>   
         _subjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubjectId == id);

    public void Create(Subject subject) 
    {
        _subjects.Add(subject);
    }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class Controllers : ControllerBase
{
    private Repository _repo;
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public Controllers(Repository repo, ILogger logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _logger = logger; 
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IActionResult CreateSubject(SubjectCreateDto subject)
    {
        if (subject == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Subject sent is null");
        }

        var subjectEntity = _mapper.Map<Subject>(subject);
        _repo.Create(subjectEntity);
       
       return Ok(subjectEntity);
    }
}
```

And these are the tests:

```
public class UnitTest1: IClassFixture<Controllers>
{
    private Repository _repo;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private ILogger _logger;

    public UnitTest1(Repository repo, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger) 
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _logger = logger;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreateSubjectTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var _subject = new Controllers(_repo, _logger, _mapper);
        var subject = new Subject()
        {
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("22de7cb0-0453-4435-a219-3157bf3e3302"), 
            Title = "History", 
            Credits = 10,
        };

        // Act
        var subjectCreate = _mapper.Map<SubjectCreateDto>(subject);     
        var result = _subject.CreateSubject(subjectCreate) as ObjectResult;       
        
        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, result!.StatusCode);
    } 
}
```

I must to admit that I avoid the usage of mocking for the repository. In step, I decided to use a simple `IList` to simulate the objects. I'm not sure if this has to do with the failure testing.

If anyone could help me, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Did you try debugging the test? while debugging check what parameters are passed while creating the Controllers object. I am not aware of what IClassFixture does but the Controllers object you are trying to create might not be getting passed the right parameters. You might have to set those parameters in the constructor of UnitTEst1 class and then create the object of Controllers class in your test.

Answer (score 1):

The unit test constructor cannot have parameters beyond those injected using `IClassFixture`. I think you have misunderstood the purpose of the `IClassFixture` class. `IClassFixture` is responsible for creating an instance of a class that does not require parameters in its constructor, and this instance is then injected into the class constructor. I'll provide an example to help you understand how your code would look when using `IClassFixture`. However, I recommend in this case not using `IClassFixture`; instead, I would create the controller instance in the unit test constructor.

UnitTest1.cs

```
public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<ControllersFixture>
{
    private Controllers _controllers;

    public UnitTest1(ControllersFixture fixture)
    {
        _controllers = fixture.Controllers;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreateSubjectTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var subject = new Subject()
        {
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("22de7cb0-0453-4435-a219-3157bf3e3302"),
            Title = "History",
            Credits = 10,
        };

        // Act
        var subjectCreate = _controllers.Mapper.Map<SubjectCreateDto>(subject);
        var result = _controllers.CreateSubject(subjectCreate) as ObjectResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, result!.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

ControllersFixture.cs

```
public class ControllersFixture
{
    public Controllers Controllers { get; private set; }

    public ControllersFixture()
    {
        // You need to initialize your dependencies (repo, logger, mapper) here.
        var repo = new Repository(); // Initialize your repo with necessary data
        var logger = new YourLoggerImplementation(); // Initialize your logger
        var mapper = new YourMapperImplementation(); // Initialize your mapper

        Controllers = new Controllers(repo, logger, mapper);
    }
}
```

I recommend you in this case do this (remove `IClassFixture` you don't need it):

UnitTest1.cs

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private Controllers _controllers;

    public UnitTest1()
    {
        // You need to initialize your dependencies (repo, logger, mapper) here.
        var repo = new Repository(); // Initialize your repo with necessary data
        var logger = new YourLoggerImplementation(); // Initialize your logger
        var mapper = new YourMapperImplementation(); // Initialize your mapper

        _controllers= new Controllers(repo, logger, mapper);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreateSubjectTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var subject = new Subject()
        {
            SubjectId = Guid.Parse("22de7cb0-0453-4435-a219-3157bf3e3302"),
            Title = "History",
            Credits = 10,
        };

        // Act
        var subjectCreate = _controllers.Mapper.Map<SubjectCreateDto>(subject);
        var result = _controllers.CreateSubject(subjectCreate) as ObjectResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<CreatedAtRouteResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, result!.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

To initializate the services you need on this controller you can do:

```
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        var repo = new Repository();
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger<Controllers>>();
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program)).BuildServiceProvider();
        mapper = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(); // Initialize your mapper with the proyect configuration, the typeof(Program) is the initial class of your proyect
    
        _controllers= new Controllers(repo, logger, mapper);
    }
```